# Magento file var-session save on different place

Tags: magento, session, var

the var-session should be safe in a filesystem or on the database. My question is: where is it possible to change the place? I will save it for a while in a file system and not in the database. A cronjob should delete it there after a month. Unfortunatel I don´t find the place for change the save option.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not configurable via the Magento admin panel. While you could alter the code to change the location, the preferred way is to make the /MAGENTO_ROOT/var/session directory a symbolic link that points to the location in the file system you prefer.